# login to website in swift using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, alamofire

Hi I wanted to create an app with swift 3 that allows the user to input their userID and Password in text fields and press a login button that will login to this website: https://login.utexas.edu/login/UI/Login

I want it to authenticate the user and store a token so that I can redirect to: https://utdirect.utexas.edu/registration/classlist.WBX
in order to get the html and scrape the webpage for the courses.

```
@IBOutlet weak var uteid: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!


    var parameter: Parameters = [:]
    var requestID: String = ""
    var sunQueryParamsString: String = ""
    var hiddenFields: String = ""

@IBAction func postRequest(_ sender: Any) {

        let urlString = "https://utdirect.utexas.edu/registration/classlist.WBX"
        Alamofire.request(urlString).responseString { response in
            print("\(response.result.isSuccess)")
            if let html = response.result.value {
                if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                    // Search for nodes by CSS selector

                    print("\nrequestID")
                    for show in doc.css("input[name='login_param_RequestID']") {
                        self.requestID=show["value"]!
                        print(show["value"] as Any)
                    }

                    print("\nsunQueryParamsString")
                    for show in doc.css("input[name='SunQueryParamsString']") {
                        self.sunQueryParamsString=show["value"]!
                        print(show["value"] as Any)
                    }

                    print("\nhiddenFields")
                    for show in doc.css("input[type='hidden']") {
                        self.hiddenFields=show["value"]!
                        print(show["value"] as Any)
                    }
                }
            }

            //creating dictionary for parameters
            self.parameter = [
                "login_uri":"/login/cdcservlet",
                "login_param_RequestID":self.requestID,
                "login_param_ProviderID":"https://utdirect.utexas.edu:443/amagent?Realm=/admin/utdirect-realm",
                "goto":"https://utdirect.utexas.edu:443/registration/classlist.WBX",
                "SunQueryParamsString":self.sunQueryParamsString,
                "IDToken1": self.uteid.text!,
                "IDToken2": self.password.text!,
                "IDButton": "Submit"
            ]

            //Wait for the GET request to complete, and then send the POST request: <<==
            Alamofire.request (urlString,method: .post, parameters: self.parameter).responseString { response in
                print("\(response.result.isSuccess)")
                print(response)
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: This is NOT a software delivery site. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask properly

Comment: @JoaoVitorino but i don't know how to use alamofire to login and authenticate the user and I can't find anything to help me

Comment: First post your code, what you have done to solve the problem, what is the output you expect and tell whats is going wrong. Until now you are just asking us to write the code for your

Comment: @JoaoVitorino is this better?

Answer (score -1):

Needless to say, make sure you check the terms of service of your web site to make sure they don't prohibit scraping as many sites do. I'd also contact the owner of the web site to see if they have a web service with which you can interact, because scraping is inefficient, fragile, and time consuming. Interacting with a web service would be much easier.

Writing a scraper is easier if you get external sniffing tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [WireShark](http://wireshark.org), and watch what goes back and forth when logging in on a browser. Then write your app to reproduce this, carefully compare your app requests and response against those generated by the web site. It also lets you identify whether they're using AJAX, and again, what those look like.

You may also want to get a HTML parser, such as [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) or [NDHpple](https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple). When you request a page (e.g. the login page), you may need to parse the `hidden` fields out of the HTML form and include them in your subsequent `POST` request. This may be a pattern you'll probably be doing a lot, so being comfortable with parsing the HTML for hidden fields is likely to be useful.

Bottom line, the scraping process generally requires requesting some page, parsing it, and creating your next request and repeating. Keep an eye out for AJAX, as there might be requests going back and forth beyond what you see in the address bar of your web browser.

---

When you are scraping web site, it's easy to look at the login page and say "OK, I just need to POST with userid and password and I'm golden".

The thing is, it's often more complicated than that. You might not think you need to worry retrieving the HTML for the login page, but you often do. Sometimes there are hidden fields on that login form (which you need to parse out). Sometimes it sets cookies. It depends.

In your case, your login page does both. So, using [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple), you might do something like:

```
func retrieveLoginPageParameters(completion: @escaping ([String: String]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request("https://login.utexas.edu/login/UI/Login")
        .responseData { response in
            guard let data = response.data, response.error == nil else {
                completion(nil, response.error)
                return
            }

            let doc = TFHpple(htmlData: data)
            guard let elements = doc?.search(withXPathQuery: "//input[@type='hidden']") as? [TFHppleElement] else {
                fatalError("bad xpath")
            }

            var parameters = ["IDToken1": self.username, "IDToken2": self.password]
            elements.forEach { element in
                    if let name = element.attributes["name"] as? String,
                        let value = element.attributes["value"] as? String {
                        parameters[name] = value
                    }
            }
            completion(parameters, nil)
    }
}
```

That retrieves the login page and parses out the hidden fields. You can then use that to login:

```
retrieveLoginPageParameters { parameters, error in
    guard let parameters = parameters, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    self.login(with: parameters) { success in
        print(success ? "successful login" : "login failed")
    }
}
```

Where

```
func login(with parameters: [String: String], completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request("https://login.utexas.edu/openam/UI/Login", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
        .responseData { response in
            guard let data = response.data, response.error == nil else {
                print(response.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }

            // you can now parse the html to make sure login was successful

            // when done, call completion handler indicating whether login
            // was successful or not; given I don't know what a successful
            // login looks like, I cannot go any further here

            completion(true)
    }
}
```

Note, I'm sending the login request to `openam/UI/Login`, because that's the `action` the `<form>` in the HTML used. Maybe after a successful login it's redirecting to some other page, but you have to send the login request to the same page referenced the the login `<form>` HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the input! the first step I need to complete before scraping is to login to the website and authenticate the user because in order to get to the class list, I have to login first. I am going to use one of the HTML parsers but am I on the right track? Or should I login a different way?

Comment: You're skipping a step. You're sending the login request without having requested the login HTML page. I know, it feels weird to request this login HTML page when it feels like it's just showing a login form, but it really has hidden fields and cookies that you often have to capture and include when you send the actual login with credentials. The cookies should be captured automatically, but you have to manually capture the hidden fields yourself (which is why we use HTML parsers).

Comment: I see. I kind of understand a little bit more after reading this: https://brennan.io/2016/03/02/logging-in-with-requests/

Comment: However, how do I know which hidden fields I need to login? at the moment I am just parsing for all of the hidden fields but is that necessary?

Comment: You probably don't need all of them, but the trick is knowing which you need and which you don't. The safest approach is to grab them all. Frankly, I suspect the cookies are more critical in this particular case, so if you're a "risk taking kind of guy" you can try skipping the hidden fields. But if you get some unexpected response after ignoring the hidden fields, try again, capturing as many of the hidden fields as possible.

Comment: Okay, I have gotten the hidden fields and edited my code above. Can you take a look at it and see if I am doing it correctly? also thank you so much for replying and sorry to bother you so much. This is one of my first projects and I'm very new to swift and I have never dealt with web development which is why I was so confused on where to begin.

Comment: I must not have been clear. I didn't want _you_ to go through the HTML parsing out all of those values. I was expecting _your program_ to do that. Specifically, it should make https://login.utexas.edu/login/UI/Login first, dynamically parse the hidden fields and then issued the second request. It must do both requests. In doing the request to https://login.utexas.edu/login/UI/Login, you'll not only get HTML with hidden fields, but also a bunch of cookies (which may end up being more critical because the cookies appear to have unique session id numbers which you have to retrieve dynamically).

Comment: oh I thought i did get the requestID and sunQueryParamString dynamically?  whenever i go to login.utexas.edu/login/UI/Login the hidden fields seem to have empty values so instead I went directly to https://utdirect.utexas.edu/registration/classlist.WBX and it redirects to a login page that have values in the hidden fields

Comment: If i am not dynamically parsing the HTML for hidden fields and cookies, how do I do that?

Comment: First, if you're going to do screen scraping, you really are going to have to get into parsing HTML. So you might as well bite the bullet on that one. Second, even if you're not going to parse the login form for hidden fields, you still need to request that page (so cookies are set for you). I've shown an example of how you might do that in my revised answer. By the way, if you're not familiar with the details of how browsers interact with web servers (e.g. the cookies, parsing html, AJAX, etc.), this might not be a good candidate for your first project. It's a non-trivial problem.